# How to output datetime in 24hrs format

Tags: c#-4.0

I tried below, but it did not output 24hrs time format.

07pm should be 19:00

```
string strTime = "2016-09-06 07:42:00";           
 DateTime Dt = DateTime.Parse(strTime);

string str24hrsformat = Dt.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `DateTime.ToString`?

Comment: Also, here's some additional reading material for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+output+date+time+in+military+24hrs+format&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: I did. I tried most of them. None can help. This why I am here.

Comment: "07 pm should be 19:00" It should, but that's not the code you posted. Also, here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Problem solved. I have to include PM or AM in the string when creating dateTime. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the PM in the initial time string

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it really is the answer here since OP would see what he needs if he added PM... Gotta love people not explaining downvotes. Also, +1'd